# cfg file not resolved when trying to import python library from zip included to a path

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I use Spark 2.4.0 + K8s cluster deployment mode + python 3.5.

I pack all libraries into zip archive and send it to AWS S3, then attach to context

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName=args.job_name, environment=environment)

sc.addPyFile('s3a://.../libs.zip')
sc.addPyFile('s3a://.../code.zip')
```

Import works, I can import any package. But if I import package, that reads some files from package-related folders - I get error:

`NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/var/data/spark-ce45d34b-8d2f-4fd0-b3d6-d53ecede8ef1/spark-6ce9d14f-3d90-4c3c-ba2d-9dd6ddf32457/userFiles-08e6e9ec-03fa-447d-930f-bf1bd520f55a/libs.zip/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg'`

How could I solve it?

PS. Use `sc.addFile('s3a:/..')` and unzipping not works because spark is running in cluster mode.

UPDATE:

I've temporary solved this by installing all packages I need to the docker container I'm using for spark workers.

Comment: Does that directory exist in your nodes?

Comment: @Rico Yes, `sc.addPyFile` makes file available for all nodes.The error happens when module tries to load config file of itself while importing (from zip).

Comment: I mean does this exist in your nodes? `/var/data/spark-ce45d34b-8d2f-4fd0-b3d6-d53ecede8ef1/spark-6ce9d14f-3d90-4c3c-ba2d-9dd6ddf32457/userFiles-08e6e9ec-03fa-447d-930f-bf1bd520f55a/libs.zip/airflow/config_templates/`

Comment: @Rico Yes
`/var/data/spark-ce45d34b-8d2f-4fd0-b3d6-d53ecede8ef1/spark-6ce9d14f-3d90-4c3c-ba2d-9dd6ddf32457/userFiles-08e6e9ec-03fa-447d-930f-bf1bd520f55a/libs.zip` exist
and `airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg` inside `libs.zip` exists too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pip-installed packages are not safe to be compressed into a zip. For example, used [Airflow v1.10.15 was not ZIP-safe](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5786dcdc392f7a2649f398353a0beebef01c428e/setup.py#L685) (not sure about new versions)